# Filter in getter on a collection

Tags: c#, collections, properties, getter-setter

```
public Schedule 
{
    public Schedule()   
    {    
        Payments = new List<Payment>();
    }

    public List<Payment> Payments 
    {
        get => Payments.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
        set { };
    }
}
```

I want to return only Active payments from a collection whenever I get it. Is there a way to make this work? The problem is the code is setting the entire collection and also doing Adds to it throughout the application so I can't just use a private variable and call

```
set { _payments = value }
```

In other words, there are places where

```
Payments = new List<Payment>();
// elsewhere
Payments.Add(payment);
```

I want to make sure whenever the list is referenced anywhere that only the items in the list that are returned are `IsActive`.

Anybody know how to make this work?

Comment: If `Payments` returns a new `List<Payment>`, that add can't work. Period, full stop.

Comment: I deleted my other comments... Do you need to keep those `Payments` for which `.IsActive` is `false`. Can `.IsActive` change while the payment is held in your collection?

Comment: Why is the question down voted? I wanted to avoid making significant changes to the current code and thought a filter on the collection would be possible

Comment: If the `IsActive` property in `Payment` is mutable, someone can acquire a reference to a payment while it is active and it can be made inactive somewhere else later. You must make the `IsActive` property immutable to be able to enforce your constraint, no matter which of the given solutions you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `Payments` to return a new collection, adding items to that new collection just isn't going to alter the collection your class owns.

This will work.

```
private List<Payment> _payments = new List<Payment>;

public IEnumerable<Payment> Payments => _payments.Where(x => x.IsActive);

public void AddPayment(Payment pmt) => _payments.Add(pmt);  

//  You can write ClearPayments(), RemovePayment(), etc.
```

You might instead want to write a subclass `PaymentList : IList<T>` that has an internal `List<Payment>`. It would have special behavior for `GetEnumerator()` and the indexer, and simply forward everything else to the private collection. That gets to be a lot of work though, when you start thinking about it.

It depends on what you really need here. If the rest of your code *needs* `Schedule.Payments` to return something that can be treated as a `List<Payment>`, something will have to change.

Comment: I marked this as the answer because yes, "something will have to change". The filter without a backing field that handles adds will not work. I was trying to avoid the extensive changes in this code base but it could probably use a refactor.

Answer (score 2):

You want to provide **controlled** access to the list, but you are also providing **raw** access to it.

As you have already figured out, that is not going to work.

I would recommend you hide the details of the implementation by providing methods instead:

```
public Schedule 
{
    private List<Payment> _payments;
    public Schedule() 
    {
        _payments = new List<Payment>();
    }

    public IEnumerable<Payment> GetActivePayments()
    {
        //Do whatever you want here, e.g....
        return _payments.Where(x => x.IsActive).ToList();
    }

    public void AddPayment(Payment payment)
    {
        //Do whatever you want here, e.g....
        _payments.Add(payment);
    }

    public void ClearPayments()
    {
        //Do whatever you want here, e.g....
        _payments.Clear();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can create your own collection class and constrain the handling of data within it. Something along these lines:

```
public class PaymentList : IEnumerable<Payment>
{
    private List<Payment> _payments = new List<Payment>();

    public IEnumerator<Payment> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _payments.Where(p => p.IsActive).GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var list = new PaymentList();
foreach (var item in list)
{
    //item would have IsActive = true
}
```